# How to mount 100% ext4 sd in Android Pie?

Tags: adb, external-sd, shell, mount

My phone (Redmi 6A) is running Android Pie(MIUI). How do I mount a 100% ext4 formatted sd card, such that it would be seen by vold? My phone is rooted. I am not experienced with the android shell commands though, and my terminal emulator cannot run adb commands.

Comment: Use [vold-posix](https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/vold-posix).

Comment: I do not have Magisk, and vold-posix does not work on >Android 8, in which I am using Android 9

Comment: I never used that personally, just know it exists. What's the purpose of being seen by vold? Why not mounting manually?

Comment: How do I mount it manually then?

Comment: Using `mount` command.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try that.

Comment: The mount command returns ```Invalid Argument```

Comment: What command did you execute? Follow proper syntax: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html

Comment: Thanks. I was able to mount the ext4 sd card successfully.